# IHttpHandler IsReusable, but is not getting re-used

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I have an IHttpHandler which I believe can benefit from re-use, because it is expensive to set up, and is thread-safe. But a new handler is being created for each request. My handler is not being re-used.

Following is my simple test case, without the expensive setup. This simple case demonstrates my problem:

```
public class MyRequestHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    int nRequestsProcessed = 0;

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        nRequestsProcessed += 1;
        Debug.WriteLine("Requests processed by this handler: " + nRequestsProcessed);
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }
}

Requests processed by this handler: 1
Requests processed by this handler: 1
Requests processed by this handler: 1
Requests processed by this handler: 1... at least 100 times. I never see > 1.
```

Am I misunderstanding how IsReusable works? Is there something else that can defeat re-use? My handler is being called from a Silverlight application if that makes any difference.

Comment: How are you attaching your handler to your application? Through web.config or programmatically?

Comment: This is my first such app. I created a new ASP.NET Web Site project in Visual Studio. To run the server, I'm running Debug from Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm asking how you've configured `MyRequestHandler` to run. For example, is it configured in your web.config, or do you have code in `Global.asax` that registers it?

Comment: Hmm, I don't really know. There is nothing in either web.config or global.asax that references MyRequestHandler. When I run the Visual Studio debugger, it starts a server, then my Silverlight app requests image tiles using the form "http://localhost:51532/MyRequestHandler.ashx?level=13&x=19&y=5&width=256&height=256
". The project is based on Jeff Prosise's article on Dynamic Deep Zoom (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd943052.aspx), btw.

Comment: If that's some visual-studio provided debug server, that could explain why it doesn't try to re-use, in itself.

Comment: That's very possible. In the end I went with usr's solution, so my original question was unimportant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IsReusable is not a guarantee.

Just refactor your handler and put all cross-request state into a different class. Clearly separating cross-request state in a web application in **best-practice anyway** because it is dangerous.

Comment: My expensive setup involves allocating up to 100 MB of memory, and let's say it can't be designed any better, so the allocation is unavoidable. I don't want to re-allocate 100 MB for each request. What "different class" could I use to persist that memory pointer, so it can be accessed by multiple requests (or multiple handlers)?

Comment: Just use a static variable pointing to an instance of your state-holding class. Or put it in the http application dictionary. Any type of static storage will do (make sure to be thread-safe, btw).

Answer (score 1):

If it's thread-safe, then you can go better than reuse anyway.

When `IsReusable` returns true then:

1. First an instance of the handler is created.
2. It's `ProcessRequest` is called.
3. It **might** be put into a pool to use again.

This means it could reduce the repeated set-up cost, but not necessarily (no guarantee) and not completely - if there are several concurrent calls to the same URI, then there'll need to be several such handlers created to handle them at the same time.

The good thing about this approach is that (when the pooling does happen), handlers don't actually have to be thread-safe.

Since yours is though, we can do better in one of two ways.

One, is to put all of your functionality into another class. Then the handler can just be a slim class where `ProcessRequest` passes through to a static instance of that one.

Similarly, we can do this with your current class using an IHttpHandlerFactory:

```
public class MyRequestHandlerFactory : IHttpHandlerFactory
{
  private static MyRequestHandler SingletonHandler = new MyRequestHandler();
  IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, string url, string pathTranslated)
  {
    return SingletonHandler;
  }
  void ReleaseHandler(IHttpHandler handler)
  {
    //do nothing
  }
}
```

With the above class, you can just change the Web.Config to refer to `MyRequestHandlerFactory` where it currently refers to `MyRequestHandler`, and it'll work perfectly.

(Unless you're not actually as thread-safe as you thought, in which case - oopsie!)